# I just happened?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, tenses

I’m a bit confused about the verb form in this phrase:

X: Can I stop by for a few minutes? I just **happen/happened** to be nearby, and I really need to use the loo.

Should **happen** be in present or past?

Additionally, can you say “I was just called stupid”? Does it sound natural?

Answer (score -2):

They're both absolutely fine; it's just a (VERY) slight shift in emphasis.

"I just happen to be nearby" implies that being nearby makes it convenient for X to use the bathroom.

"I just happened to be nearby" implies that being nearby was what made it *occur* to X that it would be convenient to use the bathroom.

Honestly, I'm trying to think of a situation in which I'd have a clear preference for one over the other, and I'm failing. They're virtually equivalent.

Comment: I just happen to have a possible counterexample in mind.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I'm not sure. I mean, if we'd been talking about this and you showed up at my door and said, I just happened to have a possible counterexample in mind, I think my answer would be the same.